How to use symmetry properly in probability
Question: A chess tournament has 128 players, each with a distinct rating. Assume that the player with the higher rating always wins against a lower rated opponent and that the winner proceeds to the subsequent round. What is the probability that the highest rated and second-highest rated players will meet in the final?
My question - I had the idea of splitting the draw into $2$ tournament brackets but my initial thought was to use symmetry i.e. the probability that player $128$ and $127$ are drawn in different brackets is $\frac{1}{2}$.
I understand the solution that there are $128$ positions for player $128$ to go into, and so player $127$ must go in $64$ of the remaining $127$ positions, but why would we not consider a symmetric approach in this instance?
And do you guys have any tips on identifying situations where we can use symmetry? Is the reason we can't use symmetry here because we are kind of sampling without replacement?

As you remark, this situation is nearly, but not perfectly, symmetric.  Thus, the symmetry argument is just an approximation.  A good approximation!  The probability that player $#2$ is in the opposite bracket is $\frac {64}{127}=0.503937008$ but that is not exactly $.5$

Not sure  there's much to say about general rules.  Symmetry applies in the limit here, and it is a very good sanity check as to the result.  Each situation has to be looked at on its own.

alright. do you think the sampling without replacement means that we can't use symmetry in this case?

As I say, you can use it as a, very useful, approximation.  But in problems with finite resources (here, the available bracket slots are the resources) symmetry is often broken, as one allocation shifts the probability for the next.
